# Why are certain Delphi SOAP RTL OpConvert.pas methods deprecated if they use a String instead of a Stream as their XML document type?

Tags: delphi, soap, stream

I have a warning in my code that I can't figure out how to remove.  The method is a utility method that is invoking THTTPRIO's FConverter field's `IOPConvert.ProcessResponse` method.

There are several overloaded versions of ProcessResponse in IOPConvert, and the one that is declared with parameter type `InvString` as the first parameter is the deprecated one.

Throughout the Delphi SOAP RTL, the trend has been away from String types and towards stream types, since Delphi 7, up to now (Delphi XE/XE2).

The question is WHY? In this case I can't even figure out how to convert my helper code unless I add an ugly string-stream wrapper:

```
TRIOHelper = class helper for THTTPRIO
    public
        function HelperMethod(aMethName: String; aSoapString: String) : TRemotable;
    end;

function TRIOHelper.HelperMethod(aMethName, aSoapString: String): TRemotable;
var 
   tmpString:String;
begin 
     //FConverter is a field in THTTPRIO
     tmpStr := GrievousXmlHackery(aSoapString);
     FConverter.ProcessResponse(InvString(tmpStr), IntfMD, MethMD, FContext);
     ...
end;
```

The code above the deprecated call is tweaking an XML document (the SOAP response) and removing some problematic elements from the incoming stream. Yes, a hack.   How should I change it,and why are strings bad in OpConvert?

I guess I need to make a String Stream or Memory Stream wrapper for tmpString? Note that in my case, the GrievousXmlHackery function removes the `<encoding>` tag when present, from the SOAP for evil reasons that remain unimportant here.

Unless there is something actually technically WRONG with the old methods and the string based apis, I'm going to put up with the warning. But if (like many places in the VCL), the deprecated warning also means "here be dragons", I'd like to know about it.

Comment: we really need a good SOAP open source lib for Delphi!! ):

Comment: The built-in SOAP RTL is really good. But it's not well documented.

Comment: my experience with SOAP is not good ): and documentation(at least in D2010) is extremely poor!

Comment: I intend to fix that by making a large library of open source demos for Delphi 2010/XE/XE2 based on the set that used to be included in Delphi 7 through 2007.  They got dropped around Delphi 2009.  I'm waiting for a response from Embarcadero; If they agree, a new open source project and wiki will be soon forthcoming.

Comment: wow, didn't knew that, you're awesome Warren!!

Comment: I really hope you get a response back and they agree! I have always struggled with SOAP (not literally - I use shower gel)! ...but jokes aside, it would be a great learning experience to see these when/if permission is granted.

Comment: The demos are on codecentral now. http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/28789

Comment: @WarrenP - Thank you, that was incredibly fast. I am checking them out right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Delphi's SOAP implementation, but why can't you just use a `TStringStream` instead?

```
function TRIOHelper.HelperMethod(aMethName, aSoapString: String): TRemotable;
var 
  Strm: TStringStream;

begin 
     //FConverter is a field in THTTPRIO
     Strm := TStringStream.Create(GrievousXmlHackery(aSoapString));

     // or
     // Strm := TStringStream.Create('');
     // Strm.DataString := GreviousXmlHackery(aSoapString);

     FConverter.ProcessResponse(Strm, IntfMD, MethMD, FContext);
     // Not sure if you or THTTPRIO is responsible for releasing the stream
     ...
end;
```

Comment: I definitely could do that. If I could rewrite GrievousXmlHackery to use a stream instead of doing everything in a temp string it would be even better, I guess.

Comment: That would make it better, since it looks like it would remove the need for `TRioHelper` altogether. (I hate `class helpers` unless there's no alternative; they're a hack that was added to shoehorn Vista support into Delphi while still supporting Win95/XP, and even the dev team that implemented them admitted so - I used to have a link to a blog post (Allen Bauer's??) advising not to use them because of that reason.)

Comment: It's one grievous hack to enable another grievous hack, in my app.

Comment: Hopefully you can reduce them a little now, then. :)